# Firebase, como redireccionar luego de iniciar sesión?

Tags: firebase, email

necesito ayuda con la redirección luego de iniciar sesión en Firebase, lo que quiero es que cuando los datos ingresados sean correctos se redireccione automáticamente a X pagina pero no tengo idea de como hacer. Este es el codigo que estoy usando:

```
const inputEmail = document.getElementById('inputEmail');
const inputPassword = document.getElementById('inputPassword');
const btnIniciarSesion = document.getElementById('btnIniciarSesion');

btnIniciarSesion.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const email =  inputEmail.value;
    const password = inputPassword.value;
    const auth = firebase.auth();
    const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));
});
```

Encontre una forma para redireccionar pero lo hace siempre así los datos no sean correctos:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if(user) 
  {
     window.location = 'home.html';
  }
});
```

Espero me puedan guiar para realizar esto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

obtuve ayuda en Stackoverflow en ingles, asi que dejo aquí la solución que me sirvio:

```
btnIniciarSesion.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const email =  inputEmail.value;
    const password = inputPassword.value;
    const auth = firebase.auth();
    const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(user => {
        location = 'home.html' //Url aqui
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    })
    promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));
});
```

Comment: OK. Gracias por la respuesta. Pero pregunto. Que pasa si un usuario pone en el navegador la ruta del documento "home.html" sin pasar por el login ?. Gracias.

Comment: en mi opinión, si vas hacer una aplicación que requiera de permisos para ciertas rutas, te recomendaría que uses algún framework como angular o react

Answer (score 0):

```
usas ahora si el validador del usuario si no esta logueado te devuelve a donde quieras y ya
function observador () {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        const dropdownMenuButton = document.getElementById('dropdownMenuButton')
        if (user) {
          var email = user.email;
          dropdownMenuButton.innerHTML=email
          console.log('el usuario es '+ email')
        } else {
          window.location.href='/index.html'
        }
      });
```

Comment: lo que hace el if es que me muestra en el menu de arriba el correo del usuario activo